# Access to Calendar API return 401 Unauthorized

Tags: authorization, office365api, office365-restapi

I'm new to office 365 and having problem with accessing rest api.
I'm trying to test the rest api of **Calendar and Mail API**, so I decided to use Postman. However, to test those APIs, I need an access token in Authorization header. To figure out how to get a token, I decided to get the sample project [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-Angular-GettingStarted) , configure, run and sign in on this local site to get the token cached in local storage and use that token for further requests in Postman. However, all requests I tested returned '401 unauthorized request'.

What I did:

- Register a new app on Azure ADD associated with O365 account
- Add full app permissions and delegated permissions.
- Update 'oauth2AllowImplicitFlow' to true in manifest file.
- Clone sample project
- In app.js, I change the alter the content of config function as following

  ```
  function config($routeProvider, $httpProvider, adalAuthenticationServiceProvider) {
      $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
          templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
          controller: 'HomeController',
          controllerAs: 'home',
          requireADLogin: true
      })

      .otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/'
      });

  // The endpoints here are resources for ADAL to get tokens for.
  var endpoints = {
      'https://outlook.office365.com': 'https://outlook.office365.com'
  };

  // Initialize the ADAL provider with your tenant name and clientID (found in the Azure Management Portal).
  adalAuthenticationServiceProvider.init(
      {
          tenant: 'mytenantname.onmicrosoft.com',
          clientId: '<my cliend Id>',
          endpoints: endpoints,
          cacheLocation: 'localStorage'
      },
      $httpProvider
      );
  };
  ```

Then I ran the app, it sign me in just fine and I can also get the token, but that token is also unauthorized to request.
I decoded the token and saw the value of 'aud', it didn't return "https://outlook.office365.com/". In [this url](https://github.com/jasonjoh/office365-azure-guides/blob/master/ValidatingYourToken.md), the author said that **"This should be "https://outlook.office365.com/" for the Mail, Calendar, or Contacts APIs"**

So what did I miss ?

Answer (score 1):

How you call the Office 365 API in AngularJS?

When signing the user in, you will only get the id_token to authenticate the user.

The aud of id_token is the tenant id (GUID).

To call the Office 365 API, you need to use AugularJS http request.

Here is a sample of sending email using Microsoft Graph API in AngularJS:

```
  // Build the HTTP request to send an email.
  var request = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/microsoft.graph.sendmail',
    data: email
  };

  // Execute the HTTP request. 
  $http(request)
    .then(function (response) {
      $log.debug('HTTP request to Microsoft Graph API returned successfully.', response);     
      response.status === 202 ? vm.requestSuccess = true : vm.requestSuccess = false; 
      vm.requestFinished = true;
    }, function (error) {
      $log.error('HTTP request to Microsoft Graph API failed.');
      vm.requestSuccess= false;
      vm.requestFinished = true;
    });
```

Before calling the API, ADAL.js will acquire another token - access token which you can used to send the email.

[image]

**UPDATE#1**

I also downloaded the sample you mentioned. To run this sample, please ensure you have the *Exchange Online > Read and writer user mail* Permission assigned in your application.

[image]

Comment: I'm using the default send mail function provided in that gihub project, and it turned out that it couldn't get the access_token

http://i.imgur.com/4500mK6.png

and I just acknowledged that I used the id_token to make API call. So now how to detect why the access_token is empty ?

Comment: I am already able to get the access token, but by entering the URLs and get the authorization code manually, not by the example project. The problem doesn't relate to permission on app's configure on azure AD, since I already set full permission for Exchange Online for it. Still doesn't know why

Comment: Can you describe more details in your question: the HTTP request to get the Calendar, the error message in 401 response. The decoded access token (JWT) will also help to troubleshoot this issue. You can decode it on https://jwt.io/